# Problems in Installation of Blackberry JDE Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java-me

I am having issues installing the BlackBerry JDE plugin. I have downloaded and installed the plugin from the BlackBerry site.  The installation ran smoothly and completed.  However when I open Eclipse the option for BlackBerry is not showing.

I don't know what the problem is exactly. I tried many things but I am heading nowhere. I want to know how to add the plugin and get started on BlackBerry development.

Comment: Iam using windows 7 and i want to know is there any issue with windows 7 for this plugin

Comment: I have problems with it with Eclipse Helios, too. I downloaded and installed the `BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.3.0.201102031007-19.exe`. It needs an emtpy folder where it installs a new Eclipse installation. You should have a purple icon on the desktop. But this installation does not have all the menus you can find in BlackBerry docs, such as "BlackBerry/Configure Blackberry Workspace". Are BB docs a little old? At http://goo.gl/vicWj BB says Helios is the last version. Confused about it...

Answer (score 3):

The default download of the [BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp) is a combination of Eclipse and the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin.  For version 1.3 and 1.5, the install directory will contain a full Eclipse Helios installation, along with the BlackBerry plugin.  You should start eclipse from that directory.

---

From the download page, one of the new features for version 1.5 is:

> Ability to download and install the BlackBerry Plug-in into an existing Eclipse environment by providing the BlackBerry Plug-in through an Eclipse update site.

So to take advantage of that, follow the instructions on "[BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse Update Site](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp)" which explain how to add the site to your existing Eclipse setup, and then install the plugin from the site.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 options, as noted above.

The blackberry way: you download the full plugin (the name is misleading, since it's a full eclipse install including  the plugin) from [here](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp).

The eclipse way: you install a 32-bit Java 6 SDK (64-bit is not supported and Java 7 has known problems with the code signing tool), then download the 32-bit Eclipse (I use version 3.7 "Indigo"), and install the plugin from Eclipse (Menu Help->Install new software, type the url "http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseupdate/3.6/java" inside the "Work with" box, then you need to select the plugin and at least a Blackberry SDK from the list)

If everything works, you should see the blackberry icon in the "About" box.

You should also see a Blackberry perspective (under Window->Open Perspective), a Blackberry menu item under "Project"), and a Blackberry section if you create a new project.

There is no such thing as a "Blackberry tab". The Blackberry development tools are integrated with the environment.

Answer (score 2):

you could have done some mistakes while the installation. I am also using in windows 7 only. Its working perfectly for me. Please delete the current eclipse and try to install as shown in this [tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/07/get-started-developing-for-blackberry.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have installed it on my new laptop just yesterday. Simple, follow the steps and you will be done. Note that the latest eclipse is Indigo and not Helios; I am using Indigo and I advocate it.

1. Go grab your [Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR1/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32.zip)
2. Unzip into ANY dammed directory. You must see a folder with "eclipse" created.
3. Double click the Violet eclipse Icon. You must now be seeing eclipse smiling at you.
4. Select the menu Help->Install New Software
5. Select a hyperlink present at label "Find more software by working with the "Available Software Sites" preferences"
6. Now select Preferences and the select the button "Add".
7. Fill up Name and Location values with the following
8. Name:**BlackBerry Java Plug-in Update Site**, Value: **"http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java"**
9. Select OK.

That's it!

Comment: You're my hero. I was following instructions from phonegap on how to set up Eclipse and use their SDK for Blackberry, but it was saying to install the eclipseUpdate/3.6/web instead of /java. However, the install would fail because of dependencies. I'm installing /java now and things are going smoothly, I'm hoping this will solve my /web problem as well.